# CSS Troublshoot

Tags: html, css

I can't figure out how to make this site fixed width so that when you are on smaller screen sizes it doesn't look messed up. Can anyone point me in the right direction? any help would be much appreciated. http://gloriacoutureco.com

Here is a link to a screenshot of what the website looks like on a smaller screen -

[image]

Comment: Please include the code here.  Include any (failed) attempts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to Use **MEDIA QUERY** FOR THIS PROBLEM ...

```
<pre>
//css Part 
body {
    background-color: lightgreen;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
    body {
        background-color: lightblue;
    }
}
</pre>
```

AT BODY part

```
<pre>

//Write your content image / paragraph / anything...

</pre>
```

For DEmo(How to use visit )>>>  http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_media_example1

when you resize your browser , you will get different color  background as you mention in media query .

Other way is : you can use Container-fluid , which will take width of device and set all contents

Answer (score 0):

You could either restart it and make a [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) website or a fluid website, like [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org). Or you can use media queries in your CSS. Basically rewritting your website but suitable for the resizing of a web browser.

[Here](http://cssmediaqueries.com/) is a good guide to learing about how to use media queries.

Answer (score 0):

Try Wrapping your body contents into a `div` and set `min-width` to the smallest acceptable width This way it will still expand accordingly but not drop below the acceptable width.

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/m/min-width/

```
<body>
    <div style="min-width: 900px;>
        <!--- sites content --->
    </div>
</body>
```

Also I noticed on your Header "Most Popular Headbands" isn't staying centered.

To align that remove the `padding-left` parameter from your H1 element and replace it with `text-align: center;` and you can even add a no wrap to prevent it from wrapping `white-space: nowrap;` but if you set min-width correctly this wont happen anyways.